# How to Edit Text From Another Class In another Class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i would like  change the text of in a class i transfered from another class in an Entry ,this is my code

```cs
public class contentPage:ContentPage
{
    public Entry TextEnrty;
    public Button doneButton;
    public contentPage()

    {
        doneButton.Clicked+=doneButtonClicked;
        Content =new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {TextEntry,doneButton}
        }
    }

    private void doneButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage= new ContentPage2(TextEntry.text)
    }
}
public class ContentPage2:ContentPage
{
    public label TextLabel;
    public Button EditButton;
    public ContentPage2(string parameter)

    {
        EditButton.clicked+=EditButtonClicked;
        TextLabel.Text = parameter;
        Content =new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {TextLabel,EditButton}
        }
    }

    private void EditButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage= new contentPage()
    }
}
```

According to the code when Text is entered in the TextEntry in ContentPage, The TextEntry.Text Is sent as a parameter to contentpage2 after doneButton is clicked, and the value is set equal to TextLabel.Text,

Now, i want to edit the TextLabel.text,but since i am not using the navigation button bit EditButton, the old text will not show in the TextEntry after i go back to edit the text.

So my problem is that , i want the old text to show when i go back to chenge the text and not an empty Entry.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The simplest answer is pass the `TextLabel.Text` back to `ContentPage1` in the same way you passed the `TextEntry.Text` to ContentPage2. Why can't you do that?

Comment: I assume the problem is because you edit text of a label. Simplest solution would be that `ContentPage` (if that page is destroyed once navigating to `ContentPage2`) would accept this text in the constructor so you can assign it once instantiated. However if `ContentPage` lives while `ContentPage2` edits that value, I'd suggest an event at `ContentPage2` that would notify `ContentPage` when the text is changed.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT , i have already tried you answer, i passed TextLabel.Text in `App.Current.Mainpage = new ContentPage(TextLabel.Text)` and place a parameter in ContentPage constructer,ie,`public ContentPage(String EditParameter)`, but i get an error at ContentPage2 constructer,ie, `public ContentPage2(Striing Parameter)` stating that , `There i no argument that that corresponds to the required formal parameter  EditParameter of ContentPage.ContentPage(String)`.

Comment: @yoger you answer i similar to jgoldberger-MSFT so please read the reply i sent jgoldberger-MSFT

Comment: I believe that's because `ContentPage2` derives from `ContentPage` that means that ctor of `ContentPage2` has to pass down your `string` parameter to the `base` class constructor.

Comment: I just noticed that there's a typo in the snippet you provided. Looks like it's `ContentPage1` that we're talking about. Ctor of that class should take the parameter. Not the `ContentPage` because it's base class and both CP1 and CP2 derive from it.

Comment: @yoger i typed the code i didnt copy and paste , there is no contentpage1 i made a mistake its only ContentPage and ContentPage2. I didnt  understand this reply you gave me  "I believe that's because ContentPage2 derives from ContentPage that means that ctor of ContentPage2 has to pass down your string parameter to the base class constructor."  so what should i do.

Comment: Please copy paste the original code first. I'll be able to explain it to you with valid example.

Comment: @yoger , please i have edited my question this time i copied and pasted.

Comment: @yoger , please i have edited my question this time i copied and pasted.

Comment: Alright so it is that the CP2 derives from CP, that means when you add parameter to the constructor of CP, CP2 will have to pass it down. See the inline example:
`class CP { CP(string parameter){ /*construct CP*/} }`
now the CP2 will look like this 
`class CP2 : CP { CP2(string parameter) : base(parameter /*or perhaps null, this is already strange hierarchy*/){/*construct CP2*/} }`

Comment: @yoger ,please i still get the same error when building ,ie,`There i no argument that that corresponds to the required formal parameter EditParameter of ContentPage.ContentPage(String)`

Comment: Can you post another snipper that includes your base class so that it compiles (or at least contain's all the custom types you're concerned about in this scenario?)? All after changes that you have made so I can see what you did so I can have a look at what is the actual problem here?

Comment: @yoger public contentPage()

{ }

Comment: @yoger for `contentPage` i added the parameter,ie, `public contentPage(string Parameter1 ){ }` and for `contentPage2` i added the `base(parameter)`,ie,  ` public ContentPage2(string parameter):base(parameter) {    }`  , please ignore my previous comment it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make a second constructor like this:

```
contentPage(string entryText)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TextEnrty.Text=entryText;
}
```

And in the line in your secon class where you "navigate" back to your class, when creating a new instance of contentPage use this new Constructor.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to ADD the constructor, not change your existing. You could run into errors when first initializing your contentPage, as an example if you have it as MainPage in App.xaml.cs

Comment: please are you saying i should add another constructor? Thats not possible.

Comment: Why should that not be possible?

Comment: You could also make a single constructor with an optional argument, like 

public contentPage(string entryText=""){//your currents constructors content plus EntryText.Text=entryText;}

That prevents you from needing to write code more than once

Comment: Wow, It WORKED,Thank you very much

Comment: And that is exactly what I suggested in my first comment (with some name changes... I had to assume that ContentPage was really called ContentPage1 because it would be bad to have a class derive from itself and/or name a class the same as a class name in the Xam.Forms SDK. Sure, you _can_ because of different namespaces, but then that can cause confusion for both the developer and the compiler.  And it does seem that your initial issue was because ContentPage2 was inheriting from ContentPage (yours, not the one in Xamarin.Forms SDK) and that is one reason why you should not re-use names.

Comment: I agree with you. "contentPage" is not a good name for a class as well since the naming conventions want classes to start with capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

you should try MVVM pattern and share viewmodel across this two view

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="sharedViewModel" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: i dont get it . my classes are in c# not xaml.